# angular 2 page refresh not firing blur

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events

We have an angular 2 component where updates (http put) happen as user enters data and tabs to next field or hits enter after data entry. On blur and `key.enter` is used to trap the event where updates are done. Blur works great since it is fired on tab and also if user navigates to another component without tabbing or hitting enter. However if user enters data and does not tab, enter or navigate to another component and instead hits the refresh button (maybe just to check if all his data got saved) then blur is not fired. What is the standard way in angular 2 to capture  the page refresh event so I can do my data update there as well?

Comment: Using HostListeners, maybe a `window:unload`

Comment: @xyz thanks for the pointer. will readup on hostlisteners.

Answer (score 0):

> instead hits the refresh button

A `refresh` is *not* considered a blur on any input that might have focus.

The only hook you have at that point is the `unload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload

Comment: thanks but if I go down the unload event rabbit hole I will now have to find a way in angular to find which input had the focus when refresh was hit. I need that inputs value to http put. Does anyone know how to get the value of the active input box value ?